# Communicating with Informix from PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, informix

Please help me to setup connectivity from PostgreSQL to Informix (latest versions for both). I would like to be able to perform a query on Informix from PostgreSQL. I am looking for a solution that will not require data exports (from Informix) and imports (to PostgreSQL) for every query.

I am very new in PostgreSQL and need detailed instructions.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't said which version you are using.  There are some limitations to be aware of but there are a wide range of choices.

Since you say this is import/export, I will assume that read-only options are not sufficient.  That rules out PostgreSQL 9.1's foreign data wrapper system.

Depending on your version David Fetter's DBI-Link may suit your needs since it can execute queries on remote tables (see https://github.com/davidfetter/DBI-Link).  It hasn't been updated in a while but the implementation should be pretty stable and usable across versions.   If that fails you can write stored procedures in an untrusted language (PL/PythonU, PL/PerlU, etc) to connect to Informix and run the queries there.  Note there are limits regarding transaction handling you will run into in this case so you may want to run any queries on the other tables using deferred constraint triggers so everything gets run at commit time.

Edit:  A cleaner way occurred to me:  use foreign data wrappers for import and a separate client app for export.

In this approach, you are going to have four basic components but this will be loosely coupled and subject to proper transactional controls.  You can even use two-phase commit if you want.  The four components are (not providing a complete working example here but at least a roadmap to one):

1. Foreign data wrappers for data import, allowing you to see data from Informix.
2. Views of data to be exported.
3. External application which manages the export aspect, written in a language of your choice.  This listens on a channel like `LISTEN export_informix;`
4. Triggers on underlying tables which make view of data to be exported which raise a `NOTIFY export_informix`

The notifications are riased on the commit and so basically you have two stages to your transaction in this way:

1. Write data in PostgreSQL, flag data to be exported.  Commit.
2. Read data from PostgreSQL, export to Informix.  Commit on both sides (TPC?).

Comment: As usual I been pointed on DBI-Link, unfortunatelly there is no even one example how to do it with informix: sample code, setup procedure. Same for perl/python. My application using regular queries and very hardly to be changed, my versions are latest for Informix and Postgres, I can install and buy everything.

Comment: In both these cases you would use it just like any other db.

Comment: My recommendation would be to connect these up at the end of the transaction, for example if you are pushing data over, use a CONSTRAINT trigger to fire your code and defer it. Otherwise you write using the standard PL reference and the language reference of your choice for connecting to the other db.  For example, if using PL/J, you'd create a JDBC connection to Informix and use it like any other JDBC connection.  With PL/Perl you'd use DBI and use like any other DBI connection.

Comment: Added what I think might be a cleaner (if more complex) way to do this using an outside client and the LISTEN/NOTIFY structure in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Ok, I solved it. Everything is simple: I created Python procedure on PostgreSQL and created view on top of it. The procedure calling dbaccess that pushing data through Linux pipe and PostgreSQL copy back to the PostgreSQL table and then to procedure and then to view. Little bit slow because of system call, but does that I wanted and might be used for any DB vendor. The same I did on Informix.

Answer (score 2):

As Chris Travers said, what you're seeking to do is not easy to do.

In theory, if you were working with Informix and needed to access PostgreSQL, you could (buy and) use the Enterprise Gateway Manager (EGM) and use the ODBC driver for PostgreSQL to allow Informix to connect to PostgreSQL.  The EGM would do its utmost to appear to be another Informix database while actually accessing PostgreSQL.  (I've not validated that PostgreSQL is supported, but EGM basically needs an ODBC driver to work, so there shouldn't be any problem — 'famous last words', probably.)  This will include an emulation of 2PC (two-phase commit); not perfect, but moderately close.

For the converse connection (working with PostgreSQL and connecting to Informix), you will need to look to the PostgreSQL tool suite — or other sources.

Comment: What do you mean PostgreSQL tool suite? Can you please  provide a link to this functionality.

Comment: I mean whatever tools come with PostgreSQL.  I don't have detailed knowledge of the product, but there are ways to write code that accesses a PostgreSQL database, and there may be other supporting tools to manage a PostgreSQL database, and somewhere in that lot there might be something useful.  Or not...as I said, I don't know.

Comment: Ok, I solved it. Everything is simple: I created Python procedure on PostgreSQL and created view on top of it. The procedure calling dbaccess that pushing data through Linux pipe and PostgreSQL copy back to the PostgreSQL table and then to procedure and then to view. Little bit slow because of system call, but does that I wanted and might be used for any DB vendor. The same I did on Informix.